# Questions regarding disassembly output

Tags: c++, optimization, assembly, x86

Consider the following code in C++:

```
bool foo(int x, int y, int z, int P) {
  return (x < P && y > P && z > P);     
}

int tryout(int iS, int iP) {
  if(foo(iS,iS,iS,iP)) {
       printf("%d", 1000);
  } else {
        printf("%d", 10);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When using Intel's C++ compiler, the code produces the following assembly code:

```
L__routine_start__Z3fooiiii_0:
foo(int, int, int, int):
        cmpl      %ecx, %edi                                    #5.15
        jge       ..B1.4        # Prob 50%                      #5.15
        cmpl      %ecx, %esi                                    #5.24
        jle       ..B1.4        # Prob 50%                      #5.24
        movl      $1, %esi                                      #5.15
        xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #5.15
        cmpl      %ecx, %edx                                    #5.15
        cmovg     %esi, %eax                                    #5.15
        ret                                                     #5.15
..B1.4:                         # Preds ..B1.2 ..B1.1
        xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #5.15
        ret                                                     #5.15
L__routine_start__Z6tryoutii_1:
tryout(int, int):
        pushq     %rsi                                          #11.28
        cmpl      %esi, %edi                                    #5.15
        jge       ..B2.4        # Prob 50%                      #5.15
        jle       ..B2.4        # Prob 50%                      #5.24
        movl      $.L_2__STRING.0, %edi                         #14.8
        movl      $1000, %esi                                   #14.8
        xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #14.8
        call      printf                                        #14.8
        jmp       ..B2.5        # Prob 100%                     #14.8
..B2.4:                         # Preds ..B2.1 ..B2.2
        movl      $.L_2__STRING.0, %edi                         #16.5
        movl      $10, %esi                                     #16.5
        xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #16.5
        call      printf                                        #16.5
..B2.5:                         # Preds ..B2.4 ..B2.3
        xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #19.10
        popq      %rcx                                          #19.10
        ret                                                     #19.10
.L_2__STRING.0:
    .byte   37
    .byte   100
    .byte   0
```

I have two questions:

1. Why are there two jumps to `..B2.4` in the `tryout` method while there is only one if-statement?
2. What does this code from the method `foo` do?

   ```
   movl      $1, %esi                                      #5.15
   xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #5.15
   cmpl      %ecx, %edx                                    #5.15
   cmovg     %esi, %eax                                    #5.15
   ```

Comment: Is this supposed to be C **or** C++?

Comment: Your call to `foo()` will always return false, so you are always going to print 10. I'm wondering if maybe the compiler initially allowed for both conditions, then during optimization added the second jump statement to call printf for 10 100% of the time, since printing 1000 will never occur.

Comment: @cad: the code is written in c++, compiled with -O3

Comment: Your expression reduced to `iS < iP && iS > iP && iS > iP`. Since `iS < iP` cannot be true while `iS > iP`, the result is 0/false. Since that will always be 0/false, jumping to `..B2.4` to print 10 will always occur regardless of the result. In fact, the `cmpl`, `jge`, and `jle` instructions shouldn't even be there anymore because it's unnecessary; they should be replaced by `jmp ..B2.4`. Not sure why that didn't happen...

Comment: @ChronoKitsune actually everything from `cmpl %esi, %edi` through `jmp ..B2.5` could just be removed--no need for a jump. The program is effectively a single call to printf

Comment: @mindcruzer Very true. Maybe the optimizer got a little too drunk and suffered from a hangover...

Comment: gcc and clang *do* compile `tryout()` down to a simple call to `printf("%d", 10)` with checking of any conditions.  https://goo.gl/R9GlRP.  You can see icc 13 being silly on that godbolt link.  gcc and clang also compile `foo()` to use `setcc` and `AND` the results together, unlike `icc`'s branching output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x < P && y > P && z > P
```

has 3 conditions in it.  Putting it inside one `if` doesn't mean it only needs one `jcc` to evaluate.  (Notice that `foo()` got inlined.  There's no `call` instruction`.)

It's typical for compilers to test & branch for each condition in sequence, if they can't combine multiple tests into one expression.  In this case, `icc` has simply inlined what it did for `foo()`, but it can leave out the 2nd `cmp` because it's testing the same two variables.  Notice how the branch target is the same for both branches, because they're both checking different parts of the condition for the same `if`.  You didn't get a 3rd `jcc` because the 2nd and 3rd conditions are identical, so the compiler combined them.

As comments have pointed out, this is a case that ICC *should* have noticed didn't require any testing at all.  One branch or the other will *always* be taken, so it could have done [what gcc and clang do](https://goo.gl/R9GlRP), and compiled it down to a simple call to printf with no checking of anything.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I figured it out too that it is inlining the method foo().